# Possible problems with using Async="true" on ASP.Net Page without certain need

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, webforms, smtpclient, sendasync

For example, I have some exception processing code in Global.asax, where I call the SendAsync() method of SmtpClient to notify myself about the error.

If the Async property of the certain page is "false", I receive no letter. So, to fix it, do I have to set Async="true" on EVERY page of my ASP.NET WebForms application? Can I get any problems here?

Async="true" is needed only for email sending in my application.

I will be grateful for any help...

Answer (score 0):

Please see full post at;
[The Dangers of Implementing Recurring Background Tasks In ASP.NET](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/)

> There are three main risks, one of which I’ll focus on in this blog
>   post.
>
> 1-    An unhandled exception in a thread not associated with a request will take down the process. This occurs even if you have a handler
>   setup via the Application_Error method. I’ll try and explain why in a
>   follow-up blog post, but this is easy to deal with.
>
> 2- If you run your site in a Web Farm, you could end up with multiple instances of your app that all attempt to run the same task at the
>   same time. A little more challenging to deal with than the first item,
>   but still not too hard. One typical approach is to use a resource
>   common to all the servers, such as the database, as a synchronization
>   mechanism to coordinate tasks.
>
> 3-  The AppDomain your site runs in can go down for a number of reasons and take down your background task with it. This could corrupt
>   data if it happens in the middle of your code execution.